# Why does \0 print different output in different system in java

Tags: java, netbeans

The below code printed different output in different system.

```
String s = "hello?vsrd".replace('?', '\0');
System.out.println(s);
```

When I tried in my system (*Linux Ubuntu, Netbeans 7.1*), it printed :

[image]

When I tried the same code in another system (*Linux Mint, Netbeans 7.1*) it printed as 
[image]

I do understand that `\0` acts as a character in java ([by referring this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623697/is-it-possible-to-add-data-to-a-string-after-adding-0-null) and obviously *s.length()* prints *10*). And, non-printable characters may be printed like this (box). But, why this behaves only on some systems? is it the difference of jdk version or OSs? I don't want an alternative code, but want to know why exactly it happens so.
You can just consider `String s = "hello\0vsrd";`.

Comment: Were both outputs printed from the output window in Netbeans?  Or only the second one?

Comment: Are locale setings the same?

Comment: What does `Charset.defaultCharset()` print on both systems?

Comment: @Rick Grashel, tried both on netbeans, see update.

Comment: The output window in Netbeans really only renders what is sent and received from command-line because it executes Ant in the background.  Presuming that the versions of Java are the same on both machines, it is likely that Mint (which is a highly tweaked version of Ubuntu) is using a different character set that has a "box" defined for a null character.

Comment: @Dukeling
there should be some reason.

Comment: @qben
`' '` could be used but makes a space. `''` cannot be used because it doesn't contain character, so it will make error.

Comment: Do you really need `'\0'`? I think you should use something else. (Maybe `' '` or `String s="hello?vsrd".replaceAll("?", "");`.)

Comment: @VisruthCV see my updated comment.

Answer (score 3):

`\0` is a non-printable character.

Additionally, in `C`, strings are traditionally terminated with `\0`, as they don't explicitly store their lengths. Some programs will simply stop printing when they reach that character.

The Netbeans console does print it, but the font might not have a glyph, not even the square, which might explain the different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the direct answer. But can be more helpful maybe.
Do you really need `'\0'`?

Maybe you could use `replaceAll()`.

```
String s="hello?vsrd".replaceAll("?", "");
```

Comment: I know those are alternative ways. I just wanted to know why it happened so. I hope @Vlad answer is right.